# Pagination links disappear when clicked on the next or any other page

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I'm having a problem with PHP pagination.

When I click on the next page to see next results, pagination links and data just disappear.

I tried various Pagination classes, but decided to stop on this solution.

Will be extremely grateful if someone helps to find a fix.

```
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<?Php
require "config_pag.php";          
$field = $_POST['field'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$page_name="search.php";
$start=$_GET['start'];
if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start)){
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}

$eu = ($start - 0); 
$limit = 2;                                 
$this1 = $eu + $limit; 
$back = $eu - $limit; 
$next = $eu + $limit; 

$nume = $dbo->query("select count(id) from posts WHERE state = '$state' AND field = '$field'")->fetchColumn();

echo "<TABLE class='t1'>";
echo  "<tr><th>ID</th><th>State</th><th>Fields</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

$query=" SELECT * FROM posts WHERE state = '$state' AND field = '$field' limit $eu, $limit ";

foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {
$m=$i%2; 
$i=$i+1;   

echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['state']."</td><td>".$row['field']."</td><td>".$row['description']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

if($nume > $limit ){ 

echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'>";

if($back >=0) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
} 

echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
$i=0;
$l=1;
for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
if($i <> $eu){
echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$l</font></a> ";
}
else { echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$l</font>";}

$l=$l+1;
}

echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";

if($this1 < $nume) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";} 
echo "</td></tr></table>";
}
?>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is at risk from sql injection

Comment: Thanks, ste-fu, it is fine. I will protect it after. Firstly need to make it just work. If you have any suggestions — looking forward to hear from you. Cheers.